# Выгрузить Dataframe в БД

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dataframe

Столкнулся с проблемой выгрузки данных из датафрейма Pandas в БД после groupby() и agg().
Пример:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame(itog).groupby(['assignee', 'project', 'sprint_date']).agg({'ocenka': ['sum','count']})
```

В результату получаю нужный мне датафрейм:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
но в этом случае в БД выгружаются только 'sum','count'.
Вот сам код выгрузки датафрейма:

```
df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

Плюс кажется, может быть проблема с тем, что один 'assignee' может участвовать в нескольких 'project'. На скринте видно этот момент.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом правильно грузить датафрейм после группировки и агрегации в БД

Comment: Привели бы пример исходных данных, был бы вам нормальный ответ. а так - смотрите в сторону метода `transform` для `groupby`.

Comment: Почему Вы сохраняете `groupby` в `mydf`, а в БД пишите `df`? Ну и пальцем в небо предположу, что `.to_sql()`  плоховато обрабатывает `pd.Multiindex`, т.к. в реляционных БД такого понятия нет. Если схлопнуть до обычных колонок, то возможно всё запишется.

Comment: @DiMithras
Как схлопнуть до обычных колонок? Не очень понимаю.

Comment: @СергейКуликов [Reverting from multiindex to single index](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverting-from-multiindex-to-single-index-dataframe-in-pandas/)